# Solving a system of Non-linear equations by Fixed Point method or Newton Raphson method

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have a system of five equations with ten variables, i.e., the radial distance $r$, polar angle $\theta$; four spin vector components ($St, Sr, S\theta, S\phi$) and four momentum components ($Pt, Pr, P\theta, P\phi$). We can set $r=15$ and $\theta = \pi/2$. $EE$ and $LL$ are energy and angular momentum. We can also give numerical value to these objects, i.e., $EE=0.95$, and $LL=1.5$

Now, we have five equations with eight variables. So, we can give numerical values to any three, i.e., $Pr, Sr$, and $S\theta$.

I want to find the initial data using these five equations using Fixed Point method or Newton Raphson method. I am finding difficulties. Can anyone help me please to find the data which satisfy these equations.

```
    EQ1 = EE + Pt + 
       1/2 (-((2 Pϕ r^2 Sθ Sin[θ]^2)/Sqrt[
           r^4 Sin[θ]^2]) + (
          2 Pθ r^2 Sϕ Sin[θ]^2)/Sqrt[
          r^4 Sin[θ]^2]);
    EQ2 = -LL + Pϕ + 
       1/2 ((2 Pt (-1 + 2/r) r^2 Sr Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/((1 - 2/
             r) Sqrt[r^4 Sin[θ]^2]) - (
          2 Pr (-1 + 2/r) r^2 St Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/((1 - 2/
             r) Sqrt[r^4 Sin[θ]^2]) + (
          2 Pθ (-1 + 2/r) r^3 St Sin[θ]^2)/Sqrt[
          r^4 Sin[θ]^2] - (
          2 Pt (-1 + 2/r) r^3 Sθ Sin[θ]^2)/Sqrt[
          r^4 Sin[θ]^2]);
    EQ3 = 1 + (Pr^2 (-2 + r))/((1 - 2/r)^2 r) + (Pt^2 (-1 + 2/r)^2 r)/(
       2 - r) + Pθ^2 r^2 + Pϕ^2 r^2 Sin[θ]^2;
    EQ4 = (Pr (-2 + r) Sr)/((1 - 2/r)^2 r) + (Pt (-1 + 2/r)^2 r St)/(
       2 - r) + Pθ r^2 Sθ + 
       Pϕ r^2 Sϕ Sin[θ]^2;
    EQ5 = -(((-2 + r) Sr^2)/((1 - 2/r)^2 r)) + 
       SS^2 - ((-1 + 2/r)^2 r St^2)/(2 - r) - r^2 Sθ^2 - 
       r^2 Sϕ^2 Sin[θ]^2;
```

Using $EE = 0.95; LL = 1.5; r = 9; \theta = 
 Pi/2; Pr = 0; Sr = 0.01; S\theta = 0.001; SS = 1;$
I simpilifed the equations and get

```
EQ1[Pt_, Pθ_, Pϕ_, Sϕ_] := 
  0.95` + Pt + 1/2 (-0.002` Pϕ + 2 Pθ Sϕ);
EQ2[Pt_, Pθ_, Pϕ_, St_] := -1.5` + Pϕ + 
   1/2 (0.` + 0.013999999999999999` Pt - 14 Pθ St);
EQ3[Pt_, Pθ_, Pϕ_] := 
  1 - (7 Pt^2)/9 + 81 Pθ^2 + 81 Pϕ^2;
EQ4[Pt_, Pθ_, Pϕ_ , St_, Sϕ_] := 
  0.` + 0.081` Pθ - (7 Pt St)/9 + 81 Pϕ Sϕ;
EQ5[St_, Sϕ_] := 0.9997904285714285` + (7 St^2)/9 - 81 Sϕ^2;
```

I was taking help from the help section, where FixedPoint[f, expr] command was used for one equation. That's why, first I was trying to to convert the system in such a way that one equation contains one variable using

```
Solve[{EQ1[Pt, Pθ, Pϕ, Sϕ] == 0, 
  EQ2[Pt, Pθ, Pϕ, St] == 0, 
  EQ3[Pt, Pθ, Pϕ] == 0, 
  EQ4[Pt, Pθ, Pϕ , St, Sϕ] == 0, 
  EQ5[St, Sϕ] == 0}, {Pt, Pθ, Pϕ, St, Sϕ}]
```

But, there was some error. Actually I want to find the initial data which satisfy EQ1, EQ2,..., EQ5.

I shall be highly thankful if someone ca help me.

Comment: I see undefined objects `EE~ and `LL` there.

Comment: How have you tried to use the fixed point method? Can you provide the code you have tried?

Comment: What are `FF1[]` etc.?

Comment: These are the equations EQ1,  EQ2, ... I just rename. EQ1 to FF1[ ].

Answer (score 1):

I take your preset values and turn them into rules

```
presets = {EE -> 0.95, LL -> 1.5, r -> 9, θ -> Pi/2, Pr -> 0, Sr -> 0.01, Sθ -> 0.001, SS -> 1}
```

Then

```
eqs = {EQ1, EQ2, EQ3, EQ4, EQ5} /. presets

Solve[eqs == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {Pt, Pθ, Pϕ, Sϕ, St}]
```

Just one answer shown...

> {{Pt -> -0.963824 - 0.0047205 I,
>
> Pθ -> -0.0337024 - 0.132886 I,
>
> Pϕ -> 0.120239 - 0.036884 I,
>
> Sϕ -> -0.0581202 + 0.0901944 I,
>
> St -> 0.392471 - 1.391 I},
>
> ...
>
> }

Comment: I was also trying in this way, but I found these imaginary values and some error in mathematica. So, I wanted to apply Newton Raphson or fixed point method.